# How to set the text size 2-3 sp smaller than the original in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to set the text size 2-3 sp smaller than the original size. How can this be done?

With "androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle.Default.fontSize" you can get the original size, but how should I extract the 2-3 sp from it?

```
Text("Hello World!", fontSize = androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle.Default.fontSize)
```

Comment: For some strange reason, `TextUnit` does not support `plus()` and `minus()` operator functions, the way that `Dp` does. I filed [a feature request for those](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206147610). It does expose `type` and `value` properties, though, so you could do some subtraction yourself and assemble a new `TextUnit` based on the result.

Answer (score 1):

The default value of font size is `14.sp`

You can choose your font size accordingly.

Screenshot from source code:

[image]

Also, `private val DefaultFontSize = 14.sp`